# Fix the error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, redux-thunk

**my error message:**

"Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'undefined'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions. See https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware for examples."

I found many answers to this error, but none helped me.

I have store in my react app, with some parts. the last part, make the error.

I'm really confused, following all the answers, how should I create the store.

**my index.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import '../node_modules/video-react/dist/video-react.css'; // import css
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers,compose ,applyMiddleware,createStore } from 'redux';
import { file, user,school,student } from "./Utilities/store/reducers";

const combine = combineReducers(
  {
    filePart: file,
    userPart: user,
    schoolPart:school,
    student:student
  }
);




ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>

  <Provider store={createStore(combine, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>

    <App />
  </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**student.js reducer:**

```
import {type} from './../functions/student'
import * as functions from './../functions/student'
const initilize = {
    all: [],
    schools:[],
    courses:[]
};

export const student = (state = initilize, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case type.get: return functions.getCurrent(state);
        case type.fill: return functions.fill(state,action.payload);
    }
    return state;
}
```

**student.js action:**

```
import * as functions from './../functions/student'
import { type } from './../functions/student'


export const getCurrent = () => {
    return { type: type.get };
}

export const fill = (post) => {
    return { type: type.fill, payload: post }
}


export const get = (students, teacherId) => {
    if (students && students.all.length > 0) {
        getCurrent();
    }
    if (students === undefined || students.all.length === 0) {
        return async(dispatch) => {
            let result = await functions.get(teacherId);
            dispatch(fill(result));
        }
    }
    else
    getCurrent();
}
```

The error occurs when I call the action  **get().**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  `(students === undefined || students.all.length === 0)` is not `true`, that method does not return anything.
But you `dispatch(get(students, teacherId))` somewhere, so essentially you `dispatch(undefined)`

Make it always return something:

```js
export const get = (students, teacherId) => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    if (students && students.all.length > 0) {
        getCurrent();
    }
    if (students === undefined || students.all.length === 0) {
            let result = await functions.get(teacherId);
            dispatch(fill(result));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I had 'else' to the functio get(), it does not help.

Comment: You noticed that in my suggestion I completely remodelled your function?

Comment: Thanks! It works.
Does this mean that if you use async (dispatch) you should wrap the whole function in it?
So really the meaning of the error, is that an undefined value was indeed returned,
And the problem is not with createStore, as I have seen in other answers.

Comment: Well, if you dispatch your function, it has to return *something* that the store accepts. That can either be an action, or a thunk function (that in doubt, does nothing).